# wordpress: add/edit link button doesn't show in visual editor

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, user-interface, interface

So the problem is there. Wordpress 4.2.2. Custom self made template(no wp edit, just bootstrap, "lightbox", jssor slider and content parsing php functions for displaying). After adding pictures on pages there should appear add/edit link and remove link in visual editor. See picture I am talking about.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSp5H.png

Everything works fine for me and at any browser(including Chrome) and different OS.
However for content maker, who is filling pages with content atm this buttons are not seen. We are using same user. His OS is win8.1, browser Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m. His screenshot is there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIlmK.jpg

Any ideas how to turn those buttons on? Already tried plugins which modify add/edit, as well turning off and turning on visual editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem wasn't solved by any cache or data clearing in browser, incognito mode are reenabling visual editor or TinyMCE fixing. As well no plugins conflicted it.
It was browser's settings problem and was solved by reinstalling Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

He doesn't have the full visual editor enabled. That's the button to the far right (kitchen sink). That said, links *should* be in basic. If it's showing fine for you and not him and you haven't added any function to block functionality, it might be a browser extension removing those buttons. Try having him use Chrome's Incognito mode.

[image]

Comment: well, writting him to do. But the thing is - I don't have the full visual editor enabled as well.

Comment: Yes I noticed that..see additional notes in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, wrote him instructions, I'll answer there once he answers.

Comment: so.. updating situation - in any other browser except for chrome it works.
He has some extensions - but they are general one(adblock, yahoo email, google things), tried on my pc with them - I have those buttons. He tried incognito mode, clearing browser cache and data. Any ideas what else we could do?